# Remove parentheses around region

Tags: balanced-parentheses, region

Is there a better alternative to this function I use to remove parens around a region? I'm looking for an Emacs builtin, or something better written, something that will remove any pairs around the selected region (ex: brackets, curly brackets, double quotes, single quotes)

```
(defun my-delete-surrounded-parens ()
  (interactive)
  ;; save where region begins & ends                                                                            
  (let ((beginning (region-beginning))
        (end (region-end)))
    (cond ((not (eq (char-after beginning) ?\())
           ;; if region not begins by (, trigger error                                                          
           (error "Char at region-begin not an open-parens"))
          ((not (eq (char-before end) ?\)))
           ;; if region not ends by ), trigger error                                                            
           (error "Char at region-end not a close-parens"))
          ;; save mark, pt, current buffer & execute body                                                       
          ((save-excursion
             (goto-char beginning)
             (forward-sexp)
             (not (eq (point) end)))
           ;; if parens are not balanced, trigger error                                                         
           (error "parens not balanced"))
          (t (save-excursion
               (goto-char end)
               (delete-char -1)
               (goto-char beginning)
               (delete-char 1))))))
```

Answer (score 8):

If you install [smartparens](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens), then you can use the function `sp-splice-sexp`, which does exactly what you are asking for.  It works on all valid types of braces and quotes, according to the current major mode.  See the [docs](https://github.com/Fuco1/smartparens/wiki/Working-with-expressions#manipulation-functions) for more details.

**Edit:** The principal advantage of `smartparens` over `paredit` (see rekado's answer) is that `smartparens` has better support for languages other than lisp.  It also allows multi-character delimiters such as triple-quotes in python or tags in XML/HTML.

Answer (score 7):

There's `paredit` which has a function `paredit-splice-sexp`, which might do what you want.

In this example `|` indicates point:

```
(hello world "no |way")  ; run paredit-splice-sexp
(hello world no way)
```

Here's another example:

```
(let ((a b))
  (fo|rmat #t "meh")) ; run paredit-splice-sexp

(let ((a b))
  format #t "meh")
```

It does *not* work on the top level, however, because that would result in an invalid s-expression.  It also does *not* operate on a region but on s-expressions.